# Is it possible to set the category of a live stream via the YouTube Live Streaming API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

This is not shown anywhere in the API documentation, but seeing as it is the youtube developers who are making the API, there must be a way.

Answer (score 2):

The category of a live stream can be set using the [`Videos.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) API endpoint invoked with a [request body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#request-body) that has:

- its property `id` set to that broadcast's ID, and
- its property `snippet.categoryId` set to the desired video category ID.

Be aware that, according to the official doc referenced above, `snippet.title` must also be set:

> `snippet.title` - This property is only required if the request updates the video resource's `snippet`.